# Python 3.8 urllib issues with read

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, python-3.8, http.client

I'm trying to do a basic GET from a local server on python 3.8 and am receiving no data back where as my old code from python 2.7 worked fine.

Here I tried doing the basic GET

```
import http.client
import urllib.request
def getData():
    data = ""
    strEPAaddress = '192.168.3.1'
    http.client._MAXHEADERS = 1000
    try:

        handler = urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=10)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
        resp = opener.open("http://%s:8080"%(strEPAaddress))
        data = resp.read()
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print("Connection Error: {}".format(e))
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions appropriately
        print("Error: {}".format(e))
```

It connects, gives me the OK and 200 but I get an empty byte as the response read with

```
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: 192.168.3.1:8080\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.8\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: WebSilicon HTTPd
header: Last-modified: Tue, 18 Nov 2007 13:09:42 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-store
header: Connection: close
[('Server', 'WebSilicon HTTPd'), ('Last-modified', 'Tue, 18 Nov 2007 13:09:42 GMT'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-store'), ('Connection', 'close')]

b''
```

Where as my code in python which is pretty much identical

```
import urllib, httplib

def getData():
    data = ""
    strEPAaddress = '192.168.3.1'
    try:
        httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
        resp = urllib.urlopen("http://%s:8080"%(strEPAaddress))
        data = resp.read()
```

Will give me when printing the response info

```
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 192.168.3.1:8080\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: WebSilicon HTTPd
header: Last-modified: Tue, 18 Nov 2007 13:09:42 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-store
header: Connection: close

<TITLE>**********</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor=white topmargin=0>
<P align=center><br>
<font face=arial size=6 color=Black><B>****** Status Summary</B></font><br><br>
<TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDERCOLOR=Black ALIGN=center BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
<TABLE WIDTH=90% BORDERCOLOR=Black ALIGN=center BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
<TR>
    <TD bgColor="75b4b4" width="90%"><font size=4>&nbsp;<B>System Info</B></font></TD>
</TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=90% BORDERCOLOR=Black ALIGN=center BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
<TR>
    <TD bgColor="9EB7B4"  width="25%">&nbsp;Manufacturer</TD>
-----------
```

I also tried wireshark and saw that the server responded to both GETs with the full html block

On my end I'm not really sure what I'm missing.  Initially it gave me the 100 header issue which is why I added the max header line
http.client._MAXHEADERS = 1000

Wireshark Response Headers.

Python 2.7
https://imgur.com/a/ilaFYFD

Python 3.8
https://imgur.com/a/ICNeMu7

Hex data right before the html from both pythons
https://imgur.com/a/GSu60Ib

Comment: What happens if you just do `resp =. urllib.request.urlopen(...)`?

Comment: Same thing.  I initially started with just urllib.request.urlopen but went into getting the debug statements out when it wasn't working.

Comment: Well, the headers sent to the device are very different between the versions, so chances are it's misbehaving somehow? A "Max headers issue" sounds like the Python HTTP client is parsing the response as headers too. Try `urllib3`?

Comment: I am unfortunately not able to use external python libraries and again the wireshark data I collected showed that the server did respond with the full html pages to both GET requests.

Comment: If you can, please show the hex+text dump from Wireshark around the response statusline and headers - I suspect the device is responding with a slightly non-standard HTTP response that used to work with Python 2's HTTP client, but doesn't with 3.

Comment: I added the two screenshots to the end of the original post

Comment: Why did you tag this with python2.7 though?

Comment: If that truly is _all_, then it looks like the device is just closing the connection without content. You could try and send the working HTTP request with a socket `import socket; s = socket.create_connection(("192.168.3.1", 8080)); s.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 192.168.3.1:8080\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'); print(s.recv(40960))` and see if the result makes some sense.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Because it worked with Python 2.7, and this clearly (for once!) is about Py2/Py3 differences?

Comment: fair enough. @Dave please do turn those screenshots into actual text though. Code formatting uses a monospace font, which makes showing a hex-and-ascii side by side pretty much trivial (provided your hex editor lets you copy, which most do).

Comment: @AKX well that just worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make my comment an actual answer:

Something about the device you're connecting to is acting up with the HTTP/1.1 message that Python 3's urllib sends, and it misbehaves.

For this very simple use case, you can just emulate a basic HTTP/1.0 connection by sending the known-good request that Python 2 sent:

```
import socket
s = socket.create_connection(("192.168.3.1", 8080))
s.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 192.168.3.1:8080\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n')

response = b""
while True:
    chunk = s.recv(4096)
    if not chunk:
        break
    response += chunk
s.close()

print(response)  # b"HTTP 200 OK\r\n...
```

Parsing the response should be easy enough; `headers, _, body = response.partition(b"\r\n\r\n")` is likely a good start.